# When I run python3.6 in terminal, it give me "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python, python-3.6

When I try to run python 3.6 it give me this SyntaxError.

```
$ python3.6
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 73, in <module>
import os
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 678, in <module>
from _collections_abc import MutableMapping
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_collections_abc.py", line 203
return await
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: This looks like Mac OS. How did you install Python 3.6?

Comment: Do you have a `PYTHONPATH` variable in your environment?

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank installed with "pip install python3.6".

Comment: @khelwood how do I look at it?

Comment: Maybe try the [official installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/).

Comment: `echo $PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank thank you it worked.

Comment: @khelwood thank you

Comment: @AabishkarShrestha What did you to that solved your problem?

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank I just installed the python3.6 again from the official site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears somehow your copy of the standard library file which defines the `collections.abc` module is corrupted. Looking through the last several versions of the file **_collections_abc.py** in the Github repository didn't show any versions where line 203 was `return await` (I didn't look through all of them, so I may be wrong).

The actual syntax error is that the file includes the line `return await`. In Python 3.6, this is invalid syntax because `await` is now a keyword which must be followed by an awaitable expression. In previous versions of Python, `await` was not a keyword, so `return await` was a valid statement.

Are you sure you installed 3.6 with the command `pip install python3.6`? and not something like `brew install python3.6`? There is currently no package for 2.7 or 3.6 called `python3.6`.

I would suggest deleting this installation and installing 3.6 either through the [official downloads](https://python.org/download) or through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) since it looks like you are on a Mac.